# Prove that $L =\{ a^n b^m c^{n\times m} \mid n, m\geqslant 0\}$ is not context free

Tags: context-free

I looked at all possible options for $vx$ when you look at $z = uvwxy$ and can't find a contradiction in the case where $b$'s and $c$'s are in $vx$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $v\in b^+c^+$, what would $v^2$ look like? (same thing for $x$)